# OSX - Ditto Compressing Command and Filename Suffix

Tags: macos, compression, ditto

I want to run this command but also have it so that the filename has a suffix that either increments or even better, I would love for it to have the date.

Eg: output_zip_directory_2022-01-21.zip

This is the command I typically use just to compress the source folder and move it to a different directory.

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent source_directory output_zip_directory_1.zip
```

Many thanks for your time, in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the _1 by $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')

It will use the result of the command date in your command:

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent source_directory output_zip_directory_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').zip
```